# How can get multiple users in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, local-storage, digital-signature

I want to get some user in `localstorage` and use it in login page.
In the following code, I was able to save only one user in localstorage, and by adding a new user, the old user is deleted and the new user is replaced.
But I want the old user not to be deleted by adding each new user and I want to add as many users as possible.

sign in page:

```
const Signin = () => {

    const [values, setValue] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onChangeInput = (name,e) => {

        setValue(pvalue => ({
            ...pvalue,
            [name]: e.target.value,
        }));

    };

    const submit = () => {
        let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]")
        users.push({values})

        localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users))
        
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(values));

        const loggeduser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        if (
            values.email === loggeduser.email &&
            values.password === loggeduser.password
        ) {
            alert("Emaill & Password is available!!!")
        }
        else{
            navigate("/");
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="text-center m-5-auto">
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <p>
                    <label>Email address:</label><br />
                    <input
                        name="email"
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput('email',e)}
                    />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password:</label><br />
                    <input
                        name="password"
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput('password',e)}
                    />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button id="btn" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Register</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signin;
```

I did various searches and did not find any results

Comment: Why do you have submit and `handleSubmit`? You should have only one function like that

Comment: Since you have handleSubmit and submit function, you are repeating keys of localstorage, for this reason your user get replaced by new one.

Comment: @Konrad Which one is right for me to use?

Comment: @PedramArabnejad you should use handleSubmit() function only.

Comment: @Asma
Submit() function should I delete it completely?

Comment: @PedramArabnejad I have written answer below, hope it really helps you.

Comment: @Asma
Thankful
Now, several users are stored, but they are not stored separately in a presentation
Is it possible to tell me what I should do?
It is saved in this way:
[{"values":{"email":"asdf@gsad.com","password":"1234"}},
{"values":{"email":"asdf@gsad.com1","password":"12345"}}]

Comment: @PedramArabnejad You should store your users in key value pair. Following link might help you : [link](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage#:~:text=Storing%20an%20object%20in%20localStorage,in%20the%20setItem()%20method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope following solution might help you :

```
 function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (
            values.email === loggeduser.email &&
            values.password === loggeduser.password
        ) {
            alert("Emaill & Password is available!!!")
 

        let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]")
        users.push({values})

        localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users))
        }
        else{
            navigate("/");
        }
    };
```

Comment: This code is correct, except you should save your users on passing If check. This would save you from future errors.